# upload de archivo con jquery, ajax y php (mvc)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

tengo el siguiente problema, tengo un input file de un formulario para subir un archivo pdf, copiarlo al servidor y guardar la ruta en la base de datos con php.

mi input file es:

```
 <div class="form-group" id="UploadArchivo">
                     <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                           <label>SUBIR EXPEDIENTE CREDITO<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                           <input type="file" id="uploadArchivo" name="uploadArchivo" class="form-control" value="">
                           <p class="help-block">Peso máximo Archivo PDF 125MB</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

esto lo recibe un archivo con javascript que usa ajax.

```
    function enviar_frm(){
  var urlprocess = 'web/ajax/ajxingarantia.php';
  var proceso = $("#txtProceso").val();
  var id = $("#txtID").val();
var archivopdf=$("#uploadArchivo").val();
  
  var dataString='proceso='+proceso+'&id='+id+'&cod_credito='+cod_credito+'&estado='+estado;
  dataString+='&detallecontrato='+detallecontrato+'&idasejuridico='+idasejuridico+'&archivopdf='+archivopdf;

  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    
    url:urlprocess,
    data: dataString,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){

       if(data=="Validado"){

            if(proceso=="Registro"){

             swal({
                 title: "Exito!",
                 text: "CONTRATO CREDITO REGISTRADO CON EXITO",
                 confirmButtonColor: "#66BB6A",
                 type: "success"
             });

             $('#modal_iconified').modal('toggle');

             cargarDiv("#reload-div","web/ajax/reload-contratocred.php");
             limpiarform();

             } else if(proceso == "Edicion") {


                 swal({
                     title: "Exito!",
                     text: "CONTRATO CREDITO MODIFICADO CON EXITO",
                     confirmButtonColor: "#2196F3",
                     type: "info"
                 });
                  $('#modal_iconified').modal('toggle');
                 cargarDiv("#reload-div","web/ajax/reload-contratocred.php");

             }else if(proceso =="SubirArchivo"){
              swal({
                title: "Exito!",
                text: "EXPEDIENTE DE CREDITO AGREGADO CORRECTAMENTE",
                confirmButtonColor: "#2196F3",
                type: "info"
            });
             $('#modal_iconified').modal('toggle');
            cargarDiv("#reload-div","web/ajax/reload-contratocred.php");

             }

       } else if (data=="Duplicado"){

          swal({
                 title: "Ops!",
                 text: "El contrato que intentas ingresaste ya existe",
                 confirmButtonColor: "#EF5350",
                 type: "warning"
          });


       } else if(data =="Error"){

              swal({
               title: "Lo sentimos...",
               text: "No procesamos bien tus datos!",
               confirmButtonColor: "#EF5350",
               type: "error"
           });
       }

    },error: function() {

        swal({
           title: "Lo sentimos...",
           text: "Algo sucedio mal!",
           confirmButtonColor: "#EF5350",
           type: "error"
       });


    }

 });

}
```

el archivo : ajxingarantia.php , el inconveniente que tengo es que pasar lo que recibe el input file

```
    <?php

spl_autoload_register(function ($className) {
    $model = '../../model/' . $className . '_model.php';
    $controller = '../../controller/' . $className . '_controller.php';

    require_once $model;
    require_once $controller;
});

$funcion = new Garantia();

if (isset($_POST['cod_credito']) && isset($_POST['estado'])) {
    try {
        $proceso = $_POST['proceso'];
        $id = $_POST['id'];

        $codCredito = trim($_POST['cod_credito']);
        $contrato = trim($_POST['detallecontrato']);
        $estado = trim($_POST['estado']);
        $codAseJuridico = trim($_POST['idasejuridico']);
      //  $ruta=trim($_POST['subirarchivo']);

      $file_name = $_FILES['archivopdf']['name'];
    $file_temp = $_FILES['archivopdf']['tmp_name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['archivopdf']['size'];
    $file_type = $_FILES['archivopdf']['type'];
    
    $ruta="web/assets/garantiascreditospdf".$file_name;
    if($file_size < 5242880){
        if(move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $location)){
        }
        }

        switch ($proceso) {
            case 'Registro':
                $funcion->Insertar_ContradoCred($codCredito, $contrato, $estado, $codAseJuridico);
                break;

            case 'Edicion':
                $funcion->Editar_ContratoCred($id, $codCredito, $estado, $codAseJuridico, $contrato);
                break;
            case 'subirArchivo':
                $funcion->ctrSubirArchivoCredito($id, $ruta);
                break;

            default:
                $data = 'Error';
                echo json_encode($data);
                break;
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $data = 'Error AJAX';
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}
```

me tira error al pasar la referencia al controlador y luego este va al model el error es:

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: archivopdf in C:\wamp64\www\GARANTIAS\web\ajax\ajxingarantia.php on line 24

no se si estoy capturando mal el input file , para hacer la validacion y subir al servidor, que no me permite guardarlo, alguna ayuda.

Comment: No estás enviando el archivo, sino sólo el nombre del archivo. La respuesta de salmortec va en la línea correcta, quizá no funcione del todo por algún detalle, pero por ahí tienes que seguir.

Answer (score 2):

Para poder subir el archivo tienes que utilizar formData.

A la hora de preparar los datos para mandar por Ajax, cambia:

```
var dataString='proceso='+proceso+'&id='+id+'&cod_credito='+cod_credito+'&estado='+estado;
dataString+='&detallecontrato='+detallecontrato+'&idasejuridico='+idasejuridico+'&archivopdf='+archivopdf;
```

Por:

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('proceso', proceso);
fd.append('id', id);
fd.append('cod_credito', cod_credito);
fd.append('estado', estado);
fd.append('detallecontrato', detallecontrato);
fd.append('idasejuridico', idasejuridico);
var archivopdf = $('#uploadArchivo')[0].files;
fd.append('archivopdf',archivopdf[0]);
```

Y en las opciones de ajax, cambia:

```
 $.ajax({
   type:'POST',

   url:urlprocess,
   data: dataString,
   dataType: 'json',
```

Por:

```
$.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url:urlprocess,
  data: fd,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
```

Por último, fíjate que en el momento que estás moviendo el archivo a su ruta final en `move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $location)` estás usando la variable `$location` que no la veo definida. Quizás la variable que quieras usar ahí es `$ruta` que la defines un par de líneas antes.

Con esto ya debería llegarte a PHP el archivo.

A ver si hay suerte

Comment: parece seguir sin funcionar.

Comment: ¿Te sigue dando el mismo error de `( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: archivopdf in C:\wamp64\www\GARANTIAS\web\ajax\ajxingarantia.php on line 24`? He hecho una prueba rápida y a mí me ha funcionado. Mira a ver en la línea donde tienes `if(move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $location)){` si `$location` lo tienes definido o deberías tener ahí `$ruta`. Aparte, `$ruta="web/assets/garantiascreditospdf".$file_name;` tienes que poner una barra después de la ruta "fija". Debería ser `$ruta="web/assets/garantiascreditospdf/".$file_name;`. A ver si ahora si lo conseguimos

Comment: Listo ya consegui mover el archivo pdf a mi carpeta destino, el inconveniente es que no me permite ingresar la ruta en la DB

Comment: Me alegro de que ya funcione.   No se exactamente a qué te refieres con ingresar la ruta en la DB... si es poner la ruta donde has guardado el documento en una tabla no debería ser difícil... es poner una columna de tipo cadena en la tabla que quieras y le pones el valor de `$ruta`.