# No me deja subir archivos y almacenarlos en MySQL con Jquery y PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, jquery, ajax

de antemano muchas gracias por su tiempo en leer y revisar!
Tengo el siguiente problema desde hace 2 días, es que no encuentro como guardar un archivo de un formulario! este es mi codigo.

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="rut">Rut</label>
    <input type="text" required  placeholder="Rut" name="rut" class="form-control" id="rut">
</div>
<div class="form-group" id="ordencnew">
    <label for="ordenc">Orden de compra</label>
    <input type="text" required  placeholder="Orden de compra" name="ordenc" class="form-control" id="ordenc">
</div>
<div class="form-group" id="imagen">
    <label for="imagen">Archivo</label>
    <input type="file" required name="imagen" class="form-control" id="imagen">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="comentario2">Comentario</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="comentario2" id="comentario2" placeholder="Comentario" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
    <input type="submit" value="Guardar Registro" onclick="guardar();" class="btn btn-primary">
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function guardar(){
var archivo = $('#imagen');
var parametros = 
{
    "guardar": "1",
    "rut" : $("#rut").val(),
    "ordenc" : $("#ordenc").val(),
    "imagen" : archivo.files[0],
    "comentario2" : $("#comentario2").val()
};
$.ajax({
    data:  parametros,
    url:   'buscar-rut2.php',
    type:  'post',
    cache:false,
    processData:false,
    contentType:false,
beforeSend: function(){
    $('.formulario').hide();
    $('.cargando').show();
}, 
error: function()
{alert("Error");},
complete: function(){
    $('.formulario').show();
    $('.cargando').hide();
    limpiar_todo();
}
}) 
}
```

**Y este es mi Codigo PHP**

```
<?php
include("../conexion.php");
if(isset($_POST['guardar']))
{ 
    $doc = $_POST['rut'];
    $ordenc = $_POST['ordenc'];
    $comentario2 = $_POST['comentario2'];

    $namefile = $_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'];

    $existe = "0";
    $alert = "";
    //CONSULTAR
      $resultados = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM personas WHERE rut = '$doc'");
      while($consulta = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados))
      {
        $existe = "1";
      }

      if($existe=="1")
      {
        //actualizar
          $_UPDATE_SQL="UPDATE personas Set 
              ordenc='$ordenc', 
              archivo1='$namefile'                
              comentario2='$comentario2'

              WHERE rut='$doc'"; 
              mysqli_query($conexion,$_UPDATE_SQL); 
      }
      else
      {
        //crear uno nuevo
        mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO personas 
          (rut, ordenc, archivo1, comentario2) 
            values 
        (
        '$doc',
        '$ordenc',
        '$namefile',
        '$comentario2'
        )");
      }

}

mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Cabe destacar que mi codigo es mucho mas amplio con mas valores y mas input, y funciona perfectamente, pero no encuentro la manera de guardar un archivo en una carpeta y su url en la base de datos, ya eh intentado de muchas maneras y no eh dado con la solución, si alguien me puede enseñar o ayudar estaría muy agradecido, muchas gracias!.

Answer (score 1):

Hace un par de días hubo una [pregunta relacionada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/506496/upload-de-archivo-con-jquery-ajax-y-php-mvc/506517#506517) con el tema de subir archivos, también te podría ayudar.

Hay varias cosas:

Antes de nada, fíjate que estás usando el `id="imagen"` en 2 sitios: tanto en el input de tipo archivo como en el bloque que lo contiene. Yo te diría que cambiaras el id del bloque que lo contiene, y dejarlo así:

```
<div class="form-group" id="imagenDiv">
  <label for="imagen">Archivo</label>
  <input type="file" required name="imagen" class="form-control" id="imagen">
</div>
```

La mejor manera para mandar archivos es usando [formData](https://es.javascript.info/formdata). En tu caso, deberías cambiar en el JS:

```
var archivo = $('#imagen');
var parametros = 
{
    "guardar": "1",
    "rut" : $("#rut").val(),
    "ordenc" : $("#ordenc").val(),
    "imagen" : archivo.files[0],
    "comentario2" : $("#comentario2").val()
};
```

por:

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('guardar', '1');
fd.append('rut', $("#rut").val());
fd.append('ordenc', $("#ordenc").val());
fd.append('comentario2', $("#comentario2").val());
var imagen = $('#imagen')[0].files;
fd.append('imagen',imagen[0]);
```

Y en las opciones en el ajax debes cambiar:

```
$.ajax({
data:  parametros,
url:   'buscar-rut2.php',
type:  'post',
cache:false,
processData:false,
contentType:false,
```

Por:

```
$.ajax({
data:  fd,
url:   'buscar-rut2.php',
type:  'post',
contentType: false,
processData: false,
```

Con esto ya debe mandar el archivo a la parte de PHP.

En la parte de PHP debes mover el archivo de la ruta temporal donde se guarda de primeras a una ruta "tuya". Para esto debes usar la función [move_uploaded_file](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.move-uploaded-file.php). Deberías hacer algo así:

```
$file_name = $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
$file_temp = $_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'];
$namefile = './files/'.$file_name; // por ejemplo. Pon la ruta que tú quieras
move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $namefile);
```

Yo creo que con estos cambios te funcionará.

Comment: Bro tampoco funciona, nose por que :/ me esta guardando es la ruta ./files/ pero no esta moviendo el archivo y menos esta guardando el nombre del mismo sino solo la ruta

Comment: Lo resulvi con el siguiente codigo amigo!

$file_name = $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
$file_temp = $_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'];
$namefile = 'subidas/'. $file_name;
move_uploaded_file($file_temp, "subidas/$file_name");

Comment: Me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto. De todas maneras, en el código que has puesto, aprovecha el valor de la variable `$namefile` y ponlo en el segundo parámetro de `move_uploaded_file` y así no tienes que repetir la ruta. Saludos!